# Defining a Turing machine for $0^n 1^n 0^1$

Tags: turing-machines, automata

I am new to understanding Turing machines and I am trying to define a Turing machine that for the language $L = 0^{n}1^{n}0^{n}$.

I am not quite sure how to give an implementation level description of Turing machine that decides L. This is what I have tried

```
Define Turing machine M = On input string w
1. Scan the input from left to right to make sure that
   it is a member of 0∗1∗0∗ and reject if it isn't.
2. Return tape head to left-hand end of tape.
3. Repeat the following until no more 0s left on tape.
4. Replace the leftmost 0 with x.
5. Scan right until a 1 occurs. If there are no 1s, reject.
6. Replace the leftmost 1 with x.
7. Scan right until a 0 occurs. If there are no 0s, reject.
8. Replace the leftmost 0 with x.
9. Return tape head to left-hand end of tape, and go to stage 3.
10. If the tape contains any 1s or 0s in that order, reject. Otherwise, accept.
```

In this case I am treating the $0^n$ at the very end as a completely new symbol. I am not sure if this is the right approach? I think I understand how to handle up to $L = 0^n1^n$ but not $0^n$ again at the end. Any help to put me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand how your question relates to the algorithm you've written. The algorithm clearly *does* handle the $0$s to the right of the $1$s, since steps 7 and 8 replace them one at a time with $x$s.

Comment: Use a graphical description of Turing machines, e.g. like [here](http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/gordon.pace/Teaching/Complexity/CoursePage/Notes/chapter5.pdf)

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Is there a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: You have given pseudo code which looks reasonable. What have you tried towards proving that it is correct? Can you translate it into a formal description of a TM? (If that's what's required of you.)